# Import data to ragged array

Tags: c, arrays

As an exercise, I have build a simple program that, given a text file of `N` lowercase words and whitespaces, populates a ragged array `char *en[N]`.

It works without great problems, apart for one: it populates the ragged array with only the last word of the input.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    char *en[100];
    char temp[20];

    FILE *p = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    char single;

    while((single = fgetc(p)) != EOF){
        if(!isspace(single))          /* Temporary store a single word */
            temp[i++] = single;
        else{
            temp[i] = '\0';
            en[j++] = temp;           /* Save stored word in ragged array */
            i = 0;
        }
    }

    printf("%s\n", en[0]);    /* Return the same than en[1] and en[99] */
    printf("%s\n", en[1]);
    printf("%s\n", en[99]);

    return 0;
}
```

I cannot understand why it goes down to the end of the input file. I am unable of detecting major issues that could suggest a wrong approach.

**Edit:**

The reasoning behind my approach was that an array of `*char` can be initialized with this form:

```
p[0] = "abc";
```

reasoning that I wrongly tried to translate in the error above, that @coderredoc brilliantly caught. As far as the dimensions of single words and inputs are concerned, I admit I did not put many attention in them. The exercise is centered on a different topic. In any case, thanks a lot your your valuable suggestions!

Comment: You have not allocated space for the strings and you are not copying them in.  You simply have an array of `char *` that are all pointing to `temp`

Comment: Aside: `char single;` should be `int single;` the type returned by `fgetc`.

Comment: never access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure the expected command line parameter was actually entered by the user.

Comment: regarding: `char single; while((single = fgetc(p)) != EOF){`  the function: `fgetc()` returns an integer, and EOF is an integer, so the declaration of `single` should be: `int single;`

Comment: this is not correct: `en[j++] = temp;`  suggest something like: `en[j++] = strdup( temp );`

Comment: regarding: `char *en[100];
    char temp[20];`  what happens if the word is longer than 19 characters?  What happens if the file contains more that 100 words?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your array of charcaters are all pointing to the same char array and then the content of the array at last changes to the last word. And you get *only* the last word.

A possible solution

```
en[j++] = temp;
```

to

```
en[j++] = strdup(temp);
```

Then you will achieve the behavior you want your program to have.

Answer (score 2):

You just found out the awesomeness of pointers, congratulations!

Seriously, `char *en[100]` is an array of pointers. `en[j++] = temp;` assigns the pointer to the first value of `temp` to a pointer at `en[j++]`. And you do this over and over again. No surprise that you end up with an array of pointers, *all of which* point to the same array `temp`, which holds the contents of the last word.

What to learn from this: a pointer merely points to some memory, and no memory copying happens when you do `en[j++] = temp;`. You have to allocate the memory yourself *and* copy `temp` to that new memory yourself.

Comment: Even if this answer is perfectly correct, I ended up with the other one. The reason is that it has been able to translate in practice the procedure that I was trying to implement. In any case, +1 for the absolutely valid and straightforward answer!